# Clickable outline around Snap SVG path

Tags: javascript, path, click, snap.svg, outline

Currently I create a small modeling tool using `Snap SVG`.

```
var p = Snap.path(pathString).attr({fill:'none', stroke:'black', strokeWidth:1});
```

creates connections between other elements.

Every element, including the paths are clickable. Since it is hard to click exactly the path I tried to create an invisible outline around the path using `Snap.filter.shadow` so that a click event could be triggered for the path:

```
var filter = this.paper.filter(Snap.filter.shadow(2,2,1));
filter.click(function() {
    do_as_if_i_clicked_the_path();
});
p.attr('filter', filter);
```

But adding a click event to the filter doesn't work.

Is there any way to create an invisible outline that is connected to the path so I can add events on it?

Comment: Try cloning the original path clone(), set a very low opacity, and add a large strokeWidth and adding the click handler to that ?

Comment: @Ian: this is a great idea, thanks for that. And using `drag` on the original is possible as well by just removing the clone on `dragStart` and adding a new one on `dragStop`. Wonderful solution. Could u put this as an answer? Would love to mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility that works quite well, is to clone the object you want to have an event on, and either scale it up, or make the strokeWidth larger, and then have a very low opacity (you can increase this just for testing and then reduce it to almost invisible).

If you add it to a group like this example, you can just put a drag on the group, so no need to remove it or anything (unless you need the clone not to be there sometimes, which makes sense).

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mn3ubuoo/)

```
var s = Snap("#svg");

var myLine = s.path('M0,0L100,100').attr({ stroke: 'black', strokeWidth: 1 });

var myClone = myLine.clone().attr({ strokeWidth: 50, opacity: 0.01 });

var myGroup = s.g( myLine, myClone );
myGroup.drag();
```